# Can I use COUNT() function in the WHERE clause? Query about Presidents

Tags: sql, count, where-clause

I have a relation Presidents(firstName,lastName,beginTerm,endTerm)
that gives information about US Presidents. Attribute firstName is a string
with the first name, and in some cases, one or more
middle initials.

Attribute lastName is a string with the last name of the president. For example,
the previous president has firstName = 'George W.' and his father has firstName = 'George H.W.'; both have lastName = 'Bush'. The last 2 attributes, beginTerm and endTerm, 
are the years the president entered and left office, respectively.

One subtlety is that Grover Cleveland served 2 noncontiguous
terms. He appears in 2 tuples, one with the beginning and ending years of his first term and the other for the second term.

The question I have is below:

There are 2 pairs of presidents that were father and son. But there are
a number of other pairs of presidents that shared a last name. Find all the last names belonging to 2 or more Presidents. Do not repeat a last name, and remember that the same person serving 2 different terms (e.g., Grover Cleveland) does not constitute a case of 2 presidents with the same last name.

I first thought the answer might be:

```
    SELECT lastName
    FROM Presidents
    WHERE COUNT(lastName) > 2
    EXCEPT lastName = 'Cleveland';
```

I'm not too sure if the COUNT() function can be used in the WHERE clause though.
Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use HAVING instead of WHERE when checking against Group functions.

```
SELECT lastName
FROM Presidents
WHERE lastName != 'Cleveland'
GROUP BY lastName
HAVING COUNT(lastName) > 2;
```

However, when solving SQL-puzzles likes this, you should never take into account the actual data. It should work for all consistent data-sets! I believe this is an actual solution to your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.lastName
FROM Presidents p1, Presidents p2
WHERE p1.lastName == p2.LastName
AND p1.firstName != p2.firstName;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! 2nd answer was the correct one. 
I too used that 1st response you gave out of instinct 
after I posted this. But I'm glad you corrected me about
consistency among data-sets.

Answer (score 2):

You constrain on aggregates using `HAVING`, and you are also missing a group by.

```
SELECT lastName
FROM Presidents
where lastName <> 'Cleveland';
group by lastname
having COUNT(lastName) > 2
```

Comment: The group by is implicit when there are no group functions in the select clause.

Comment: only in mysql, did op specify db?  And even then, I'd say it's a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is an id field as well,

```
select id, lastname, count(*) differentguycount
from presidents left join
(select id, firstname, lastname count(*) sameguycount
from presidents 
group by id, firstname, lastname
having sameguycount > 1 ) temp on temp.id = presidents.id
where temp.firstname is null
group by id, lastname 
having differentguycount > 1
```

As noted, the OP did not specify his database engine which could cause syntax errors.  For example some databases might not allow you to use aliases in the having clause.